# converting js variable to php

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript variable into php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515590/javascript-variable-into-php)

Okay lets imagine I've a javascript variable "x"

```
<script>
var x="jsvar";
</script>
```

Now I want its value in php variable `$y` `<?php $y; ?>` How to do it.

Okay few people are confused i wanted to know is it possible if yes then how ??
if this isn't possible then comment here i'll remove it.

Comment: in PHP how? are you passing it to PHP?

Comment: That variable exists in the browser, a php variable exists on the server, two very separate places. can you please elaborate on what your use is and we can suggest a method?  The first thing that comes to mind is to submit a form that sends that value to the server, but, again, it depends on what you want

Comment: your options are ajax, POST, GET, href which one you want

Comment: Someone needs to understand, that when javascript ir executed, the server has done it's job - there is no way to get back to it [PHP] in the current request. You have to make another request, perhaps, via ajax.

Comment: @Briedis Thanks got my answer.

Comment: MB, Please post your answer then if ComFreek's answer didn't suffice or accept his.

Comment: And please use the search next time, this question has been asked a hundred times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass it to your PHP script, either via AJAX or via a formular with a submit button.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){}; // change
xhr.open("POST", "your-script.php");
xhr.send("x="+x);
```

And the PHP script can look like this:

```
<?php

$y = isset($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] : '';
echo $y;

?>
```

Comment: is it possible with simple javascript or not ??

Comment: Yes! Look at the first code - this is (simple) JavaScript.

Comment: ok can i ask one more question sorry i'm php developer but really bad in js what XMLHttpRequest(); can do ???

Comment: You can send requests to other scripts and servers with that object. This is also called AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML). Here are probably more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: okay thanks dude my mind is too much clear than before now with js thanks for help thumbs up